# C# .NET Machine Language "Feature" class generation

Tags: c#, machine-learning, dynamic

I am working on a Microsoft ML project. The `Feature` class required by the Microsoft ML libraries is hardcoded in all examples I've found.

This `Feature` class, as shown here:

```
public class Feature
{
    [LoadColumn(1), ColumnName("A")] 
    public float A { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(2), ColumnName("B")] 
    public float B { get; set; }
    ...
    [LoadColumn(n), ColumnName("X")] 
    public float X { get; set; }
}
```

is used to lazy-load the schema from a CSV file and for generating the Sample that the ML training code is run against, specifically in the

```
mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Feature, Prediction>(model).
```

My problem is I have over 2,000 feature entries that are being used to test against the Label. And these Features will change from use to use (maybe 1800 today, 2300 tomorrow).

I am not sure whether I have to worry about `LoadColumn` and `ColumnName` qualifiers if I handle the `Feature` class the way I want.

I need to be able to:

- Read in a CSV file and dynamically generate the Feature class where each property is a name from the CSV column headings. This is currently solved as:

```
mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile(dataPath, options);
```

- Reference this class in the ML libraries, as the class, `Feature`.
- Create an instance of the Feature class and reference each property natively.

I've tried "dynamic" and "expando." This didn't work as the ML libraries didn't recognize those classes and you can't cast the classes as other classes because the implementations are different. They appear to be an integrated way to handle `IDictionary` for dealing with key/value pairs that I've used under other circumstances (but don't work here).

I would like a substitution for this class for use in lines of code like this:

```
mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Feature, Prediction>(model).
```

I would like to create the Feature class at runtime. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to make a suggestion on how to change Microsoft ML? If so, this isn't the place to do it. If not, what is your specific question?

Comment: I would like to create the Feature class at runtime. How do I do it?